# android mediaSession getPosition() always returns 0

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, runnable, android-seekbar, android-mediasession

I am trying to get the current position so that I can progress the seek-bar in my media player app. However, every time I call:

```
getSupportMediaController().getPlaybackState().getPosition();
```

It returns 0 if the media is playing and if it is paused it returns -1. I searched a lot for a solution with no success and I tried everything.

By the way I put the code above inside of a runner so that it gets executed every 1 second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PlaybackStateCompat` is just a wrapper object to get the playback information through your `Mediaplay` or `Exoplayer` (whatever you're using)

You need to update the playback state object in your `MediaSessionCompat` using the setState method in the `PlaybackState.Builder`

```
setState
```

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/PlaybackStateCompat.Builder.html#setState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/PlaybackStateCompat.Builder.html#setState(int,%20long,%20float))

```
setPlaybackState
```

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.html#setPlaybackState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.html#setPlaybackState(android.support.v4.media.session.PlaybackStateCompat))

Comment: Thank you, i will take a look at it soon.